# Which one is having better complexity f1 = (n+m) +(n+m)log(n+m) or f2 = n*m

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Which function `f1` or `f2` have better *time complexity* if

```
f1 = (n + m) + (n + m) * log(n + m)
```

and

```
f2 = n * m
```

Comment: It is easy to see that for larger values of n, m (n+m) + (n+m)log(n+m) ~ (n+m) because (n+m)(log(n+m) + 1 ) ~ (n+m). Where as n*m will be much larger at larger values of n,m. Hence (n+m) + (n+m)log(n+m) is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *depends*. To choose the winner from

```
f1 = (n + m) + (n + m) * log(n + m) 
f2 = n * m
```

we should know what `m` and `n` are; what is the *relation* between `n` and `m`. For Instance

Let `m` be constant:

```
f1 = O((n + m) + (n + m) * log(n + m)) = O(n + n * log(n)) = O(n * log(n))
f2 = O(n * m) = O(n)
```

`f2` is better.

Let `m ~ n`:

```
f1 = O((n + m) + (n + m) * log(n + m)) = O(2 * n + 2 * n * log(2 * n)) = O(n * log(n))
f2 = O(n * m) = O(n * n) = O(n**2)
```

now `f1` is a better choice

Finally, let `m ~ log(n)`:

```
f1 = O((n + m) + (n + m) * log(n + m)) = O(n + log(n) + n*log(n + log(n))) = O(n * log(n))
f2 = O(n * m) = O(n * log(n)) = O(n * log(n))
```

`f1` and `f2` have equal complexities